# How can I create a gradient utility in Tailwind CSS using tailwind.config.js and plugins?

Tags: tailwind-css

To create a gradient using arbitrary values I use this code:

```
gradient from-[#ff0000] via-[#00ff00] to-[#0000ff]
```

I know I can use `@apply` to create a custom utility. But How can I turn it into a utility class like `custom-gradient` in the `tailwind.config.js` using plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`addUtilities()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-utilities), [`addComponents()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-components), [`addBase()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-base-styles), et al to create custom utility classes with Tailwind.

Thus for your example, consider something like:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
      addUtilities({
        '.custom-gradient': {
          backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff)',
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="custom-gradient w-10 h-10"></div>
```